# ConTeXt: How to collapse two sequential page numbers to "f." in index (register)

Tags: formatting, context, indexing

**Background**

For collapsing or expanding page numbers in indexes / registers, you can use  `\defineregister[name][compress=yes|no]`, e.g.

```
\defineregister
  [photographer]
  [compress=yes]

\starttext
  \dorecurse{4}{%%
    Foo
   \photographer{Yousuf Karsh} \page}

 \completephotographer   
\stoptext
```

which will result in an index that subsumes the page references to "1-4".

(Example taken from http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineregister.)

---

**Problem**

The compress parameter works fine, but it also collapses when we have exactly two sequential page numbers, e.g. "1-2"

Unfortunately, this is very uncommon in German. Instead of "1-2" you would write "1f." when an entry refers to exactly two sequential pages.

---

**Question**

Is it possible to subsume page references that encompass exactly two sequential pages to e.g. "1f." while collapsing references that refer to more than two pages to e.g. "1-3"? If so, how would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hack into the display of the pagerange in ConTeXt.

```
\defineregister
  [photographer]
  [compress=yes]

\unprotect

\unexpanded\def\registerpagerange#1#2#3#4#5#6#7%
  {\registerpageseparator
   \global\setconstant\c_strc_registers_page_state\plusone
   \dostarttagged\t!registerpagerange\empty
   \dostarttagged\t!registerfrompage\empty
   \withregisterpagecommand{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
   \dostoptagged
   \ifnum\the\numexpr#6-#3\relax=1
     f.%
   \else
     \registeronepagerangeseparator
     \dostarttagged\t!registertopage\empty
     \withregisterpagecommand{#1}{#5}{#6}{#7}%
     \dostoptagged
   \fi
   \dostoptagged}

\protect

\starttext
\dorecurse{1}{Foo\photographer{Foo Bar} \page}
\dorecurse{2}{Foo\photographer{John Doe} \page}
\dorecurse{4}{Foo\photographer{Yousuf Karsh} \page}

\completephotographer   
\stoptext
```

[image]